# Изменение CSS style через JS

Tags: javascript, css, style, img

Хочу по нажатию на стрелки изменять размер картинки на определённое число px. Но вместо этого срабатывает лишь раз и больше не меняется. Отчего так? и как правильно наладить. Чувствую что легко и логика понятна. Но вот с реализацией малость трудновато. Пока только учусь. Спасибо.

JS:

```
let inp = document.querySelector(".i-10");
let img = document.querySelector("img");

inp.onkeydown = function (e) {
    console.log(e);
    if (e.code == "ArrowUp") {
        img.style.height += "50px";
    }

}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="i-10">
    <img src="https://telegram.org.ru/uploads/posts/2018-05/1526473044_9.png" alt="">



    <script src="script.js"></script>
```

CSS:

```
img {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let inp = document.querySelector(".i-10");
let img = document.querySelector("img");
let i = 1;
inp.addEventListener('keydown', (e)=>{
  if( e.code == 'ArrowUp' ){
      let d = 50 * i;
     img.style.height = d + 'px';
  }
 i++
})
```

```css
img {
      width: 150px;
      height: 150px;
  }
```

```html
<input type="text" class="i-10">
    <img src="https://telegram.org.ru/uploads/posts/2018-05/1526473044_9.png" alt="">
```

Comment: Можно ли это как то упростить до значений "+=" значение ? Я так понимаю ${} - это ES6 ?

Comment: @Павел так проще понять ?

Comment: да спасибо) Интерполяцией пока не пользовался, но научился. не мог понять как её написать, оказывается через обратную галочку у буквы ё. Не знал)

Comment: @Павел удачи ...

Answer (score 2):

В условие добавьте код для определения текущего состояния(для IE свое):

```
let height =  parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(img, null).height)
```

И как уже указали выше, задаем строчное значение:

```
img.style.height = `${height + 50}px`;
```

Так будет выглядеть весь код:

```
let inp = document.querySelector(".i-10");
let img = document.querySelector("img");

    inp.onkeydown = function (e) {
        console.log(e);
        if (e.code == "ArrowUp") {
            const height =  parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(img).height)
            img.style.height = `${height + 50}px`;
        }

    }
```

Подробнее: https://learn.javascript.ru/styles-and-classes

Можно немного упростить, если пока не удобна интерполяция:

```
let height =  parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(img).height)    
height += 50
img.style.height = height + 'px'
```

Comment: эм... неужели нельзя это как то упростить?) Мне как новичку в этом не совсем понятно такое усложнение) Код должен быть простым как мне кажется)

Comment: Через getComputedStyle забираем текущие стили элемента - вроде не сложно. Получаем строку с единицами измерения, 'px' надо отрезать - выделяем число из строки через parseInt - сравнимо с обычным приведением типов и не должно вызывать сложностей. Добавили к результату 50 - так легко, как вы просили) К результату добавили единицы измерения 'px' - не сложно.